# Computationally, which makes more sense when loading subviews into a view

Tags: ios, objective-c

From an expense point of view, which option provides the best computational results when adding subviews to a `UIView`'s hierarchy:

**Scenario 1**

In `viewWillAppear:animated` or `willLayoutSubviews` remove all subviews of the container view using `[[aView subviews] makeObjectPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperView]`, reset all pointers or properties and then (re)initialise all subviews and add them to the container view hierarchy.

**Scenario 2**

Initialize and add all subviews in the `viewDidLoad` method (called once only, thus only adding them to the view hierarchy once, then in the `viewWillAppear:animated` or `willLayoutSubviews` methods setting the constraints or frames for each subview.

Answer (score 1):

Scenario 2 is much more faster than the first one. Creating and deleting views is expensive you  should try to limit as much as possible.

If you are using autolayout setting the constraints can also be done in the viewDidLoad, and setting the frame is not recommended.

So the best is to create and add all the subviews in the viewDidLoad set up the autolayout constraints there and do not set the views frame, only the constraints in other methods if needed.

Comment: This was my thought pattern initially, depending on the number of subviews in the hierarchy, etc. I tend to use option 2 more, especially lately, but have found it to have some caveats with child view controllers.

Comment: But are you sure that you should redo constraints every time? What changes so much that you have to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to your condition there is [another condition](http://www.raywenderlich.com/31166/25-ios-app-performance-tips-tricks) :

Take the situation where you need to present a view when the user taps a button. There are at least two approaches to this:

1.Create the view when the screen is first loaded and hide it; then when you need it, show it.

2.Do nothing until you need to show the view. Then, create the view and show it, all at once.

Each approach has its own pros and cons.

> Using the first method, you consume more memory because you
>   immediately create the view which holds on to that memory until it’s
>   released. However, when the user does taps the button, your app will
>   appear more responsive as it only needs to change the view’s
>   visibility.
>
> Taking the second approach will have the opposite effect; by creating
>   the view only when it’s required, you consume less memory; however,
>   the app won’t appear as responsive when the button is tapped.

Comment: I tend to switch between these 2 approaches, on a case by case basis, depending on the complexity of the view required to be added. I suppose it comes down to how often you think the required view will need to appear, and whether or not you release the pointers when you dispose of the view.

Comment: yes it depends on you and on requirement to present view but not disposing the pointers keeping them may cause memory issues.

Comment: The only pointers I keep are property pointers and those usually require some form of constraint change further down the line.